# Progress query to remove duplicates based on number of duplicates

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

Our accounting department needs pull tax data from our MIS every month and submit it online to the Dept. of Revenue.  Unfortunately, when pulling the data, it is duplicated a varying number of times depending on which jurisdictions we have to pay taxes to.  All she needs is the dollar amount for one jurisdiction, for one line, because she enters that on the website.

I've tried using DISTINCT to pull only one record of the type, in conjunction with LEFT() to pull just the first 7 characters of the jurisdiction but it ended up excluding certain results that should have been included.  I believe it was because the posting date and the amount on a couple transactions was identical.  They were separate transactions but the query took them as duplicates and ignored them.

Here is a couple of examples of queries I've run that have been successful in pulling most of the data, but most times either too much or not enough:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT LEFT("Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code", 7), "Taxable-Base", "Posting-Date"
    FROM ARInvoiceTax
    WHERE ("Posting-Date" >= '2019-09-01' AND "Posting-Date" <= '2019-09-30') 
    AND (("Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code" BETWEEN '55001' AND '56763') 
    OR "Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code" = 'Dakota Cty TT')
    ORDER BY "Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code"
```

Here is a query that I can to pull all of the data and the subsequent result is below that:

```
    SELECT "Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code", "Taxable-Base", "Posting-Date"
    FROM ARInvoiceTax
    WHERE ("Posting-Date" >= '2019-09-01' AND "Posting-Date" <= '2019-09-30') 
    AND (("Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code" BETWEEN '55001' AND '56763') 
    OR "Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code" = 'Dakota Cty TT')
    ORDER BY "Sales-Tax-Jurisdiction-Code"
```

Below is a sample of the output:

```
Jurisdiction | Tax Amount | Posting Date
-------------|------------|-------------
5512100City  |  $50.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100City  |  $50.00    | 2019-09-03
5512100City  |  $70.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100Cnty  |  $50.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100Cnty  |  $50.00    | 2019-09-03
5512100Cnty  |  $70.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100State |  $70.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100State |  $50.00    | 2019-09-02
5512100State |  $50.00    | 2019-09-03
5513100Cnty  |  $25.00    | 2019-09-12
5513100State |  $25.00    | 2019-09-12
5514100City  |  $9.00     | 2019-09-06
5514100City  |  $9.00     | 2019-09-06
5514100Cnty  |  $9.00     | 2019-09-06
5514100Cnty  |  $9.00     | 2019-09-06
5515100State |  $12.00    | 2019-09-11
5516100City  |  $6.00     | 2019-09-13
5516100City  |  $7.00     | 2019-09-13
5516100State |  $6.00     | 2019-09-13
5516100State |  $7.00     | 2019-09-13
```

As you can see, the data can be all over the place.  One zip code could have multiple different lines.  What the accounting department does now is prints a report with this information and, in a spreadsheet, only records (1) dollar amount per transaction.  For example, for 55121, she would need to record $50.00, $50.00 and $70.00 (she tallies them and adds the total amount on the website) however the SQL query gives me those (3) numbers, (3) times.

I can't seem to figure out a query that will pull only one set of the data.  Unfortunately, I can't do it based on the words/letters after the 00 because not all jurisdictions have all 3 (city, cnty, state) and thus trying to remove lines based on that removes valid lines as well.

Comment: you have a primary key in your table ?? ... you should add  the query you are using  a proper data sample .. your actual result and your expected result

Comment: I've added some sample queries that I've run that pull most of the correct data but either remove too much or not enough and, when I tally up my amounts, I don't match the amount that I should be matching (which comes from a valid report that we can run).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `select distinct`?  If the first five characters are the zip code and you just want that:

```
select distinct left(jurisdiction, 5), tax_amount
from t;
```

Comment: I've tried that but, the problem is, it removes either too many lines or not enough.  As you can see, some jurisdictions have city, cnty, state while others only have city, state, and so on... and in addition, some lines may have 2 lines for city, perhaps with different amounts or with the same amounts, and I need to capture all of those because they're valid amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Take only City/County/.. whatever is first

```
select jurisdiction, tax_amount, Posting_Date
from (
    select *, dense_rank() over(partition by left(jurisdiction, 7) order by substring(jurisdiction, 8, len(jurisdiction))) rnk
    from taxes -- you output here
)
where rnk=1;
```

Sql server syntax, you may need other string functions in your dbms.

[Postgresql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=13e2d606db60fb2be8a106b394fba3fd)

Comment: I apologize, I updated the post to reflect that this is a Progress database.  Queries are pretty much the same but I will try this out -- will need to modify it a bit I believe.

Comment: See the dbfiddle.